# Google Analytics 4 Data API: Is there a way to use segments with runReport? If not, are there plans for it to be implemented?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I used to be able to utilize segments created in the UI with the API, but it looks like it was removed in GA4. I know audiences can be used as a stop-gap, but they don't have the historical view that segments allow for. Anyone find a workaround or hear of an upcoming enhancement to include?

I was expecting segments to be available in the API like they were prior to GA4.